# Accelerate QR-Encoding with ZXing

Tags: java, android, bitmap, qr-code, zxing

I'm currently working with a lot of QR-Codes in an Android project, for which [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) is my preferred library.

To actually display the generated QR-Code a Bitmap is created with the information from the encoding.

```
QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
BitMatrix matrix = writer.encode(message, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, px, px);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(px, px, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
for (int x = 0; x < px; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < px; y++) {
        bitmap.setPixel(x, y, matrix.get(x,y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

This works just fine, however it's terribly slow. Even for rather small Bitmaps it takes several seconds for the entire process.

Is there a way to intelligently speed up this procedure (e.g. parallelisation) or even a better library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That part could be parallelized with threads or find a C version. Alternatively find a third-party paid library which should be optimized (although more for reading than indica creation).

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should find a way to use Java's Thread construct.

Comment: `setPixel` is slow for bitmaps. It's more efficient to first write the pixels into an `int` or `short` array, then create an `IntBuffer` or `ShortBuffer` instance with it and finally to create the bitmap from the buffer.

Comment: Awesome, it's significantly faster. IntBuffer does distort the image but a ShortBuffer works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

I have had the same problem in this sense, I managed to accelerate my qr code loading significantly by following this guy:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vWHbCr_OWM

Hope this will help anyone who struggles with this and comes across this thread.

Actually perhaps i can save you the trouble:

in gradle:

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
```

In code:

```
        String myStringToEncode = "Something";
        MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(myStringToEncode, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,200,200);
        BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
        Bitmap bitmpap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
```

And then finally I call my ImageView control by its variable

```
       imgQR.setImageBitmap(bitmpap);
```

Comment: Cool...that looks promising.

Comment: this helped. QR is generated instantly.